# Insert data to different tables

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

```
<td>
    <label id="" class="" for="">Surname/Last Name
        <span class="required">*</span>
    </label>
</td> 
<input type="text" id="" name="lname" size="20" required value="" class=" " aria-required="true" />
<td>
    <label id="" class="" for="">Agency
        <span class="required">*</span>
    </label>
</td>
<td>
    <input type="text" id="agency" name="agency" size="30" required value="" class=" " aria-required="true" />              </td>
<td>
    <label id="" class="" for="">Organizer
        <span class="required">*</span>
    </label>
</td>
<td>
    <input type="text" id="trorganizer" name="trorganizer" size="30" required value="" class=" " aria-required="true" />
</td>
```

```php
 //my php code here
 $lname=strtoupper($_POST['lname']);
 $agency=strtoupper($_POST['agency']);
 $trorganizer=strtoupper($_POST['trorganizer']);


 $sql1 = "INSERT INTO personalinfo (lname) VALUES ('$lname')"; 
 $sql2 = "INSERT INTO pep (agency) VALUES ('$agency')"; 
 $sql3 = "INSERT INTO training (trorganizer) VALUES ('$trorganizer')";

//I think I have a problem with my sql code
     mysql_select_db('DATABASENAME');       
     $retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );          
     if(! $retval )             
     {
        die('Could not enter data: ' . mysql_error());
     } 

     echo "Data added successfully!";
     mysql_close($conn);            
   }    
}
```

Anyone can help me how to insert data into different tables? I can't save these data. Thanks for your help. It'll much appreciated!
Thanks!

Comment: sql strings won't execute by themselves, don't you have any query code?

Comment: Which API are you using to connect with?

Comment: `$retval = mysql_query( $sql $conn );` you're missing a comma, for one thing.

Comment: @Fred-ii- thanks! i forgot. but i still have error in my sql

Comment: You're welcome, but which error is that?

Comment: You're also referencing a non-existant variable `$sql` for your query and not using any reference variables for the other queries also. You'd be best to use `mysqli_` and multi-query in order to fire up all 3 at the same time. You also tagged as `javascript` and `jquery`, relevance?

Comment: It's going to be really hard to give you a definite answer if I don't know what all the parts are to get your code going. You haven't told us which API you're using to connect with, only the fact about `mysql_` functions to query with. Not to mention what I asked above. If your connecting with anything other than `mysql_` then that would be one of the reasons why your code is failing. Till I know exactly what it is I'm dealing, with, I cannot help you any further. Please take it up with the person who has given you an answer below. Good luck.

Comment: Plus, I don't even know if your code contains `<form></form>` tags and is using a POST method along with a submit button. So that's another thing that's unclear.

Comment: **SQL Injections everywhere!** Please use `mysql_real_escape_string()` on all of your variables going into SQL queries.

Comment: Also, please note, `mysql_` functions are **deprecated** as of PHP 5.5. See: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may help you:

```
<form action='your_script_name.php' method='post'>
<table>
<tr>
<td>
<label id="" class="" for="">Surname/Last Name
<span class="required">*</span>
</label>
</td> 
<input type="text" id="" name="lname" size="20" required value="" class=" " aria-required="true" />
<td>
<label id="" class="" for="">Agency
<span class="required">*</span>
</label>
</td>
<td>
<input type="text" id="agency" name="agency" size="30" required value="" class=" " aria-required="true" />
</td>
<td>
<label id="" class="" for="">Organizer
<span class="required">*</span>
</label>
</td>
<td>
<input type="text" id="trorganizer" name="trorganizer" size="30" required value="" class=" " aria-required="true" />
</td>
<td>
<input type="submit" value='Submit' name='submit'/>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

You PHP script:

```
$lname=strtoupper($_POST['lname']);
$agency=strtoupper($_POST['agency']);
$trorganizer=strtoupper($_POST['trorganizer']);

$db_con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'database_user_name', 'database_password');
if (!$db_con) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db('database_name', $db_con) or die('Could not select database.');

$sql1 = "INSERT INTO `personalinfo` (`lname`) VALUES ('$lname')"; 
$sql2 = "INSERT INTO `pep` (`agency`) VALUES ('$agency')"; 
$sql3 = "INSERT INTO `training` (`trorganizer`) VALUES ('$trorganizer')";

// command to execute query
$retval = mysql_query($sql1);          
if(!$retval ) {
    die('Could not enter data: ' . mysql_error());
}
$retval = mysql_query($sql2);          
if(!$retval ) {
    die('Could not enter data: ' . mysql_error());
}
$retval = mysql_query($sql3);          
if(!$retval ) {
    die('Could not enter data: ' . mysql_error());
}

echo "Data added successfully!";
mysql_close($conn);
```

Hope this may help you.

Answer (score -1):

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `personalinfo` (`lname`) VALUES ('". $lname ."')");

mysql_query("INSERT INTO `pep` (`agency`) VALUES ('". $agency ."')");

mysql_query("INSERT INTO `training` (`trorganizer`) VALUES ('". $trorganizer ."')");
```

You only need to have these lines of code to insert. You only need an if statement if you want to validate the queries.

Answer (score -2):

```
<?php

$sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `personalinfo` (`lname`) VALUES ('". $lname ."')");

$sql2 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `pep` (`agency`) VALUES ('". $agency ."')")

$sql3 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `training` (`trorganizer`) VALUES ('". $trorganizer ."')");

?>
```

Comment: Instead of dropping in code, an explanation would be beneficial for the OP as well as anyone else visiting the question.

Comment: why would you suggest using a deprecated and insecure extension?

Comment: We also have no idea as to which API the OP is using to connect with.

Comment: You can look at the OP's updated question, and my comment about it. You can take it from there, good luck ;-)

Comment: Sorry, mysqli->query then. If he compares, he can see what he did wrong.